# Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT

Tags: swift, sigabrt

I'm working on a playground from a tutorial I'm following, and I'm using the file that they gave me (without changing it). Unfortunately I'm getting this error `Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT'.

Here is my code, the error comes up at `people.filtered(using: allAge61)`

```
class APerson: NSObject {    // Must inherit from NSObject or NSPredicate will fail at runtime
    let name: String
    let age: Int 
    
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    
    // description lets you pretty print this class' instances in the sidebar
    override var description: String {
        return self.name + " - \(self.age) years old"
    }
}

/*:

and a bunch of People

*/

let groucho = APerson(name: "Groucho", age: 50)
let chicco  = APerson(name: "Chicco", age: 61)
let harpo   = APerson(name: "Harpo", age: 45)
let zeppo   = APerson(name: "Zeppo", age: 61)

let people: NSArray = [groucho, chicco, harpo, zeppo]
// using a NSArray here because predicates work with them, not with regular Swift Arrays

/*:

we can get __all people of age == 61__ with a simple predicate

*/

let allAge61 = NSPredicate(format: "age = 61")

people.filtered(using: allAge61)
```

Comment: Rather than using a predicate, have you attempted to use filter?

Comment: Don't waste your time with those *objective-c-ish* tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The NSPredicate refers to the string 'age' but the class isn't key-value coding compliant for the 'age' property.  If you make your class like this:

```
class APerson: NSObject {
    @objc let name: String
    @objc let age: Int
```

Then you can make it work. KVC is the feature of the Obj-C runtime that lets you go from a string like "age" to the actual age getter/setter method, and when it's trying to parse the string "age = 61" and convert "age" into "the age function", it's unable to because the property isn't marked as being @objc

Or go all Swifty:

```
struct Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    
    var description: String {
        "\(name) - \(age) years old"
    }
}

let groucho = Person(name: "Groucho", age: 50)
let chicco  = Person(name: "Chicco", age: 61)
let harpo   = Person(name: "Harpo", age: 45)
let zeppo   = Person(name: "Zeppo", age: 61)

let people = [groucho, chicco, harpo, zeppo]

people.filter { $0.age == 61 }
```

Comment: This works, thank you for the explanation.